# Scrapy crawl nested urls

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

**Introduction**

As i have to go more deeper in crawling, i face my next problem: crawling nested pages like: https://www.karton.eu/Faltkartons

My crawler has to start at this page, goes to https://www.karton.eu/Einwellige-Kartonagen and visit every product listed in this category.

It should do that with every subcategory of "Faltkartons" for every single product contained in every category.

**EDITED**

**My code now looks like this:**

```py
import scrapy
from ..items import KartonageItem

class KartonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "kartons12"
    allow_domains = ['karton.eu']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.karton.eu/Faltkartons'
        ]
    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['SKU', 'Title', 'Link', 'Price', 'Delivery_Status', 'Weight', 'QTY', 'Volume'] } 
    
    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.xpath('//div[@class="cat-thumbnails"]')

        for a in url:
            link = a.xpath('a/@href')
            yield response.follow(url=link.get(), callback=self.parse_category_cartons)

    def parse_category_cartons(self, response):
        url2 = response.xpath('//div[@class="cat-thumbnails"]')

        for a in url2:
            link = a.xpath('a/@href')
            yield response.follow(url=link.get(), callback=self.parse_target_page)

    def parse_target_page(self, response):
        card = response.xpath('//div[@class="text-center articelbox"]')

        for a in card:
            items = KartonageItem()
            link = a.xpath('a/@href')
            items ['SKU'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="delivery-status"]/small/text()').get()
            items ['Title'] = a.xpath('.//h5[@class="title"]/a/text()').get()
            items ['Link'] = a.xpath('.//h5[@class="text-center artikelbox"]/a/@href').extract()
            items ['Price'] = a.xpath('.//strong[@class="price-ger price text-nowrap"]/span/text()').get()
            items ['Delivery_Status'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="signal_image status-2"]/small/text()').get()
            yield response.follow(url=link.get(),callback=self.parse_item, meta={'items':items})

    def parse_item(self,response):
        table = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-info-inner"]')

        items = KartonageItem()
        items = response.meta['items']
        items['Weight'] = a.xpath('.//span[@class="staffelpreise-small"]/text()').get()
        items['Volume'] = a.xpath('.//td[@class="icon_contenct"][7]/text()').get()
        yield items
```

In my head it starts at the the start_url, then i visits https://www.karton.eu/Einwellige-Kartonagen, looking for links and follow them to
https://www.karton.eu/einwellig-ab-100-mm.On that page it checks the cards for some information and follow link to the specific product page to get the last items.

Which part(s) of my method is/are wrong?
Should i change my class from "scrapy.Spider" to "crawl.spider"? or is this only needed if i want to set some rules?

It could be still possible, that my xpaths of the title,sku etc may be wrong, but at the very first, i want just build my basics, to crawl these nested pages

My console output:

[image: console output]

finally i managed to go through all these pages, but somehow my .csv-file is still empty

Comment: I executed your spider and here how it behaved for me: Crawled the `start_urls` page, selected 6 objects in the var `card`, each object had a link. Yielded and crawled 6 requests, every selector in `parse_item` returned empty, no item got yielded.

Comment: Can you give me a hint, what i have to correct at first? Do recursive crawlers always have to work with rules or is it still possible without?

Comment: It's unclear for me what the spider should do. For example, your spider reaches this page https://www.karton.eu/Zweiwellige-Kartons but can't scrape anything because the XPaths (in `parse_item` method) don't match any paths on the page (at least for me it doesn't).  Should they scrape the content there or follow on to further pages like https://www.karton.eu/zweiwellig-ab-500-mm

Comment: My plan was set like this: it starts from <https://www.karton.eu/Faltkartons> its first destination is <https://www.karton.eu/Einwellige-Kartonagen> after visiting that page it should start with all articles of <https://www.karton.eu/einwellig-ab-100-mm> and save values like title,link,price and so on. After doing that, it should go to <https://www.karton.eu/einwellig-ab-200-mm> and repeat its work. My complete goal is that it does this behaviour with alle products of every category. Now i start to recheck my xpaths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments you provided, the issue starts with you skipping a request in your chain.

Your `start_urls` will request this page: https://www.karton.eu/Faltkartons
The page will be parse by the `parse` method and yield new requests from https://www.karton.eu/Karton-weiss to
https://www.karton.eu/Einwellige-Kartonagen

Those pages will be parsed in the `parse_item` method, but they are not the final page you want. You need to parse between the cards and yield new requests, like this:

```
for url in response.xpath('//div[@class="cat-thumbnails"]/div/a/@href')
    yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url.get()), callback=self.new_parsing_method)
```

Example here, when parsing https://www.karton.eu/Zweiwellige-Kartons will find 9 new links from

- https://www.karton.eu/zweiwellig-ab-100-mm  to...
- https://www.karton.eu/zweiwellig-ab-1000-mm

Finally you need a parsing method to scrape the items in those pages. Since there are more than one item, I suggest you to run them in a for loop. (You need the proper xpath to scrape the data.)

### EDIT:

Re-editing as now  I observed the page structure and saw that my code was base on the wrong assumption. The thing is that some pages don't have the subcategory page, others do.

Page structure:

```
ROOT: www.karton.eu/Faltkartons
 |_ Einwellige Kartons
    |_ Subcategory: Kartons ab 100 mm Länge
      |_ Item List (www.karton.eu/einwellig-ab-100-mm)
        |_ Item Detail (www.karton.eu/113x113x100-mm-einwellige-Kartons)
    ...
    |_ Subcategory: Kartons ab 1000 mm Länge
      |_ ...
 |_ Zweiwellige Kartons #Same as above
 |_ Lange Kartons #Same as above
 |_ quadratische Kartons #There is no subcategory
    |_ Item List (www.karton.eu/quadratische-Kartons)
      |_ Item Detail (www.karton.eu/113x113x100-mm-einwellige-Kartons)
 |_ Kartons Höhenvariabel #There is no subcategory
 |_ Kartons weiß #There is no subcategory
```

The code bellow will scrape items from the pages with subcategories, as I think that's what you want. Either way I left a `print` statements to show you pages that will be skipped due to having no subcategory page. In case you want to include them later.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import KartonageItem

class KartonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "kartons12"
    allow_domains = ['karton.eu']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.karton.eu/Faltkartons'
        ]
    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['SKU', 'Title', 'Link', 'Price', 'Delivery_Status', 'Weight', 'QTY', 'Volume'] } 
    
    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.xpath('//div[@class="cat-thumbnails"]')

        for a in url:
            link = a.xpath('a/@href')
            yield response.follow(url=link.get(), callback=self.parse_category_cartons)

    def parse_category_cartons(self, response):
        url2 = response.xpath('//div[@class="cat-thumbnails"]')

        if not url2:
            print('Empty url2:', response.url)

        for a in url2:
            link = a.xpath('a/@href')
            yield response.follow(url=link.get(), callback=self.parse_target_page)

    def parse_target_page(self, response):
        card = response.xpath('//div[@class="text-center artikelbox"]')

        for a in card:
            items = KartonageItem()
            link = a.xpath('a/@href')
            items ['SKU'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="delivery-status"]/small/text()').get()
            items ['Title'] = a.xpath('.//h5[@class="title"]/a/text()').get()
            items ['Link'] = a.xpath('.//h5[@class="text-center artikelbox"]/a/@href').extract()
            items ['Price'] = a.xpath('.//strong[@class="price-ger price text-nowrap"]/span/text()').get()
            items ['Delivery_Status'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="signal_image status-2"]/small/text()').get()
            yield response.follow(url=link.get(),callback=self.parse_item, meta={'items':items})

    def parse_item(self,response):
        table = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-info-inner"]')

        #items = KartonageItem() # You don't need this here, as the line bellow you are overwriting the variable.
        items = response.meta['items']
        items['Weight'] = response.xpath('.//span[@class="staffelpreise-small"]/text()').get()
        items['Volume'] = response.xpath('.//td[@class="icon_contenct"][7]/text()').get()
        yield items
```

#### Notes

Changed this:

```
    card = response.xpath('//div[@class="text-center articelbox"]')
```

to this: (K instead of C)

```
    card = response.xpath('//div[@class="text-center artikelbox"]')
```

Commented this, as the items in meta is already a `KartonageItem`. (You can remove it)

```
def parse_item(self,response):
    table = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-info-inner"]')
    #items = KartonageItem()
    items = response.meta['items']
```

Changed this **in the** `parse_items` **method**:

```
    items['Weight'] = a.xpath('.//span[@class="staffelpreise-small"]/text()').get()
    items['Volume'] = a.xpath('.//td[@class="icon_contenct"][7]/text()').get()
```

To this:

```
    items['Weight'] = response.xpath('.//span[@class="staffelpreise-small"]/text()').get()
    items['Volume'] = response.xpath('.//td[@class="icon_contenct"][7]/text()').get()
```

As `a` doesn't exists in that method.

Comment: do i need the for loop before the card variable? or where do i have to place it? i guess i am somehow stuck.. I also get an error in  ```...cat-thumbnails"]/div/a/@href')``` the ")" is always marked

Comment: I've seen you manage to request all the pages. If your spider isn't yielding any items, probably means they are not populated. Try to log/print the return of the selectors in the `parse_item` method. I believe they wil return empty.

Comment: @y.y I just executed your spider, it seems now that you have one function too many. Let me illustrate: This page https://www.karton.eu/900x160x65-mm-einwellige-Faltschachtel is the final page to be scraped right? Or it should raise new requests from somewhere? This page that I just mentioned is falling in the `parse_target_page` instead of `parse_item`. Inevitabile the return for the `card` var is empty, it stops there and it doesnt yield any items. Check my original answer, will add a version of your code.

Comment: url you mentiond before, should not be scraped. <https://www.karton.eu/Faltkartons> this is the start_url, there are 10 "categories" on the next page <https://www.karton.eu/Einwellige-Kartonagen>now it should open this "subcategory" <https://www.karton.eu/einwellig-ab-100-mm> thats where i want my information, but some information are only stored at the actual page of a product <https://www.karton.eu/113x113x100-mm-einwellige-Kartons>

Comment: and this method should be done for alle other subcategories of my start_url <https://www.karton.eu/Faltkartons> the url you mentioned above is of the root category.

Comment: @y.y All right, now I saw the full structure in the page. Please, check my answer again after the edit.

Comment: sorry for my very late answer, but i was busy at the weekend. Thanks for your time! i didnt know, that the different construction of some categories can be my error source. thanks for all :)

Comment: can i ask you something? i thought i have to use"a.xpath('.//xxxxx" when i dont want to check whole html page, but in my last parse_item function, i use "response.xpath('.//xxxx", can you explain me why?

Comment: Sure. Variables have a defined [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) which means that the `a` var exists inside of `parse_target_page` but not inside the `parse_item` method. Besides, the page that actually lands on `parse_item` is a single item page, so you don't need a loop to parse between several items in that page, as there is only one.